# Sniff the traffic of sim card

Tags: sniffer, simcard

I wonder if Sim Card traffic can be sniffed? I mean only the internet connection when it makes to requests to several websites. Sniff those traffic by WireShark maybe?

**P.S:** not messages, only network traffic, where it is sending data and what kinda.

Is it possible with special hardware?

Comment: SIM does not communciate, the device does

Comment: I *think* what you are asking is how to sniff data traffic sent over the cellular network, and not wifi. If that's true, you do need special hardware.

Comment: This is not a security question but a networking/mobile question. Now that you have the keywords you need, you should be able to work it out on your own.

Comment: @schroeder Hey, I was googling much and I found the RTL-SDR device. Will it do the job?